# List files on directory on phonegap build

Tags: android, file, cordova

Hi im currently trying to create an gallery app with phonegap build, but i cant read files from the local storage. I`m using this function:

```
function listDir(directoryEntry){

 var directoryReader = directoryEntry.createReader();

 directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){ // success get files and folders
    for(var i=0; i<entries.length; ++i){
      alert(entries[i].name) // this is just for checking purposes, no matter what  i       put here it wont fire
    }
 }, function(error){ // error get files and folders
    alert(error.code);
 });
}

  function getFileSystem(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){ //    success get file system
    var sdcard = fileSystem.root;
    sdcard.getDirectory('dcim',{create:false}, function(dirEntry){
        listDir(dirEntry);
    }, function(error){
        alert(error.code);
    })
    }, function(evt){ // error get file system
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    });
  }


  getFileSystem();
```

The listDir function wont even fire (the error function wont too). I have tried to add an "OnDeviceReady" listener to call the getFileSystem() function but it wont work too, plus i have tried toons of ways, even using the official phonegap docs, but it can`t read my directory. Anyone know how to do this (i`m currently using android)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one knows the answer??

Comment: have you tried to just list the files from the `fileSystem.root`?  Good to doing simpler things first and get those working then move on to more advanced things.

Comment: also - it might be a benefit to remove the `function(fileSystem)` from the `window.requestFileSystem` and call that as a separate function.

Comment: One last thing - did you install the `file` and `file-transfer` APIs?

Comment: Solved using a onDeviceReady listener to call the function, and it was conflicting with another jquery function too (you need to call the listener before everything)

Comment: @sagits can you please post your solved code

Answer (score 2):

You need remember that the cordova api is async.

This code read the list of files in my app external storage directory:

```
    function getFilesList(callback) {
        console.log('getFilesList');
        var fileList = [];

        function onDirResolved(dir) {
            var reader =dir.createReader();
            reader.readEntries(function(entries) {
                console.log('readEntries');
                for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                    if (entries[i].name.indexOf(".fototoon") != -1) {
                        fileList.push(entries[i].fullPath);
                    };
                };
                console.log('fileList ' + fileList);
                callback(fileList);
            }, errorHandler);
        };

        function onFsResolved(fs) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
                cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
                onDirResolved, errorHandler);
        };

        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            onFsResolved, errorHandler);

    };
```

The callback function will receive the list of files read.